# Generate multiple pdf with Dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I want to generate multiple PDFs in one foreach. When I run my Code, it also generates mulitple PDFs with the right name and saves it in the right folder. But the strange thing is, that only the first PDF that is generated has text in it and looks like I want it to be, and the others are all empty PDF-Files. Can someone explain, what I did wrong?

```
//here I get from my Database all bills, that are saved in my Database

 $rgAll = $this->rechnungDatabase->getRGs();
        
        foreach ($rgAll as $rgInfo){

            $dompdf = new Dompdf();

            $kundenid = $rgInfo->kundenid;
//here I get the User from my User Database
            $userInfo = $this->indexDatabase->getUser($kundenid);


            ob_start();
//this is a function to find my html site, the first two values are needed to find the file and the array gives the values, that are needed for the html site
            $this->pageload("Rechnung", "kundenrechnung", [
                'rgInfo' =>$rgInfo,
                'userInfo' => $userInfo,
            ]);    

            $html = ob_get_contents();
            
            ob_get_clean(); 

            $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
            
            // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

            // Render the HTML as PDF
            $dompdf->render();

            //$dompdf->stream("Rechnung".$rgInfo->rgnummer, array("Attachment"=>1));
            $output = $dompdf->output();

            //the PDF is now in the right folder
            $filepath= __DIR__."/../../PDFRechnung/Rechnung$rgInfo->rgnummer.pdf";
            file_put_contents($filepath, $output);

            unset($dompdf);

        }
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Instead of `ob_get_clean()`, try `ob_end_clean()`

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it still only generates for the first pdf file text and the other are still empty

Comment: Just an idea... in case you have any `require_once` or `include_once` within `$this->pageload()`, try to change them to `require` or `include` and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much @guido faecke, I really had the require_once inside my pageload() and this was also the Problem, now it works :)